# Send file download request using JQuery POST

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

I am rewriting some code that used to use GET and replaced it with POST.

The download URL used to be a GET request to

```
https://myurl/getfile?fileid=1234&filetype=pdf
```

Now, I changed that to

```
https://myurl/getfile
```

and put the `fileid=1234&filetype=pdf` in the POST body.

I did this using jquery's post method as:

```
function postCall(url, param) {
    $.post(url, param);
}
```

The server side is written using Java and I tried to reused the old code for GET, which write the file binary into the servlet's stream.

However, my browser does not prompt user for download, which used to do for GET.

Previous posts on stackoverflow did suggest that AJAX should not be used for file download. But what is the alternative way for me to use? The request is not generated by a form though.

Many thanks.

Comment: I don't know java, but basically you must put the file bytes in the response and then set the content-type to the corresponding file ending. Hope  this helps

Comment: Can you show relevant parts from your server side code as well?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a form on the page (or create one dynamically using jQuery), and then have that form do the post submission (using jQuery's "submit" function or "trigger('submit')" on the form).  This way the request won't be done asynchronously in the background.  If the "getfile" script responds with a file with Content-disposition: attachment, it should download.

That said, I'm not sure the browser will "prompt" the user in this scenario--this is dependent on the browser (whether or not a dialog appears to save the download, or if it automatically downloads the file without a prompt).

Comment: Thanks Andy. Sounds like a solution. I will try this.